# Select AS to simplify structure of returned array

Tags: mysql

From a select like this:

```
"SELECT `ScO`.`id` as `ScI`, `ScX`.`type` as `SxT` FROM ... etc
```

I would like rows to be returned as,

```
[] => Array
  ['ScI'] => *
  ['SxT'] => *
```

I am getting,

```
[] => Array
  ['ScO'] => Array
             ['ScI'] => *
  ['ScX'] => Array
             ['SxT'] => *
```

I dont need the extra nesting and hope im missing a simple syntax solution. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run that query in mysql nothing like ScO or ScX is exposed at all. So if you're getting those entities in your app it might be in your row mapper it happens.

Comment: Thankyou I forgot i was using a framework function to run the query, ill just check...